# VLOOKUP() between a file that is on my local drive and a file that is online

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Pretty straightforward but I need to apply the VLOOKUP() formula to a workbook that is online and shared between other members of a team, from a workbook that is on my local drive.

Is there a way to do this or both files need to be downloaded to my local drive?

Thanks

Comment: That would be really scary if one could put online a shared excel sheet that pulls data from my hard drive.  I really doubt this is possible with formula or code on the online sheet.

Comment: It's the other way around really, pulling data from the shared excel sheet into my local excel sheet. I'm gonna put the VLOOKUP() formula in my Local excel sheet searching columns that are on the shared sheet. Sorry for not explaining correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - and it shouldn't scary if pemisission have been set up correclty- and you don't let others see your folder structure etc./keep sensitive material passowrd protect etc.

for instance [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hIw0fN6j6SOXbk69ag?e=D3Bnjj) is a file that I've shared with everyone (read only) and it comprises 3 columns - the first two are static (A-D, fruit etc.) and the 3rd is a lookup to my local drive (which may very well display #n/a! since you don't have access to this file (another reason why you may be able to use common files, but won't necessarily be able scrape info from others drives unless they have explicitly granted acesss).  Even then - you'd really only have access to a speific file I guess.

**online file**

```
=VLOOKUP(B4:B7,[B.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$3:$B$6,1)
```

[image: online file referencinog file on local macine (drive 'Z')]

**Local file**

Likewise, you can lookup from the local file to the online one using someting like:

[image: local machine to online lookup]